# How do I get VirtualBox 4.3 to allow internal private networks from Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

The Vagrant documentation states that internal networks can be configured thus:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4", virtualbox__intnet: true
```

However, this results in the following error:

/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/childprocess-0.3.9/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:36:in `initialize': all arguments must be String: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "modifyvm", "0fdc3dfe-756c-4f27-864e-ed393e13e0ce", "--nic1", "nat", "--nic2", "intnet", "--intnet2", true] (ArgumentError)

when run with VirtualBox 4.3.

Answer (score 12):

The value expected is no longer a boolean flag, but the name of the internal network you want to use:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4", virtualbox__intnet: "name"
```

works fine.